# Elasticsearch 5.5 Cross Cluster Search setup issues

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to setup cross cluster search.

My issue is all my ES clusters are behind an nginx proxy with basic auth

I can access the elastic rest endpoint by requesting nginx endpoint:

```
https://<username>:<password>@<ngix-enpoint>:<ngix-port>
```

Can I use this endpoint and basic auth to setup cross cluster search?

Current `elasticsearch.yml` config:

```
search:
  remote:
    cluster_one: 
        seeds: <ngix-enpoint>:<ngix-port>
    cluster_two: 
        seeds: <ngix-enpoint>:<ngix-port>
```

Where shall I add auth information?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, elasticsearch cross-cluster search feature requires tcp connection, it can't be configured with http endpoint.

Unfortunately, official elastic documentation doesn't cover it explicitly, but pay attention at port numbers used in [config examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cross-cluster-search.html#_configuring_cross_cluster_search):

```
search:
    remote:
        cluster_one: 
            seeds: 127.0.0.1:9300
        cluster_two: 
            seeds: 127.0.0.1:9301
```

Those port numbers are from [default range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html#_tcp_transport) 9300-9400 of `transport module`.
It is possible to configure nginx to proxy tcp connections to elasticsearch, example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35521557/4091526).
If your cross cluster search node is located in the same, **dedicated subnetwork**, as remote cluster, it is considered a good practice to expose port 9300 and connect directly to remote cluster nodes.