# How do I establish a remote connection to a PostgreSQL database hosted in a container on a server with ports: 127.0.0.1:5432:5432?

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx

I'm running my applications using Docker compose.
And a database service section in 'server.yml' look like this:

```
db:
    env_file: .env
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    command:
      [
        "postgres",
        "-c",
        "log_statement=${db_log_statement}",
        "-c",
        "log_destination=stderr",
      ]
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${db_user}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${db_pass}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${db_user}
    volumes:
      - news-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - "${db_port}"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:${db_port}:${db_port}"
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U ${db_user}
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 40
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "1"
```

The database, let's call it 'pguser', is not accessible from the internet.
But, sometimes, I would like to connect to it remotely.
So, I need to solve how to:

1. Setup nginx on the server.
2. Define the correct URL to connect to the database. I'm using Dbeaver.

I've tried:

1. For nginx:

```
server {
    listen     x.x.x.x:5432;
    gzip off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5432;
    }
}
```

2.For URL:
`jdbc:postgresql://185.235.130.227:5432/pguser`

It's not worked.
I need some headlines how to move forward.
Thanks.

Comment: How do you connect to the server in the first place to manage the docker containers? Instead of using nginx to make the database publicly available on the internet, I would recommend to use ssh port forwarding.

Comment: Notice you'd need to [configure nginx for raw tcp connections, not as a http server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337122/1048572)

Comment: Bergi, thanks! It's the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward the port using your SSH client:

```bash
$ ssh -L 5433:localhost:5432 user@host
```

Then, access your PostgreSQL locally on port 5433.